# Erro ao executar um Trigger Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, trigger

Tenho a seguinte Trigger gerada no meu banco de dados:

```
SET TERM ^ ;



CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER ATUALIZA_CODNCM FOR EST_ADICIONAIS
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0
AS
begin
UPDATE est_adicionais

set id_ncm = (select ncm.id from est_adicionais inner join ncm on
                            (est_adicionais.ncm = ncm.numero)
                            where est_adicionais.ncm = new.ncm and est_adicionais.codigo = new.codigo)
                            where codigo = new.codigo;

end
^


SET TERM ; ^
```

Só que ao executar o comando abaixo tenha a seguinte saída:

```
update est_adicionais e set e.st = '010' WHERE e.codigo = 135;
```

Saída:

```
Invalid token.
invalid request BLR at offset 258.
function HASHMD5 is not defined.
module name or entrypoint could not be found.
```

Ao executar em separado os comando de Select e Update os 2 são executados sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Você tem a UDF HASHMD5 no seu BD?

Comment: @wesleyluan acredito que não devo ter? Isso já vem nativo ou é preciso adicionar separadamente?

Comment: Existe alguma trigger que está utilizando esta UDF ?

Comment: Como identifico o uso desta UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema se dava por conta do Firebird instalado no computador estar corrompido faltando a UDF HASHMD5, dai no caso de precisar executar acusava a falta de tal complemento.

Para sanar o problema foi feito a remoção dos componentes do Firebird e feito novamente a instalação do mesmo.